# The Goal of Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been playing Clash of Clans for 4 days now. After the 3-day beginner's shield was lifted, I was attacked and suffered 100% damage. I thought, that was it, this attacker has taken over my village and now I have to build a new village. But no..the village was still mine, my buildings were not *actually* destroyed, and I was awarded a 16 hour shield, and I could continue to play.

So I don't understand; what's the goal, or eventual result of the game? What I initially thought was that clans would fight each other and the last remaining clan in the world is the winner. On an individual level, I figured destroying an opponent's town hall will give me their village , then I'll have 2 villages to manage and stuff like that. But no, you can still play after your village has been destroyed 100%.

So when do we truly lose or truly win in this game? What is the goal to be achieved?

Comment: It's a free time management game; in Supercell's eyes, your goal is to spend a TON of money.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a bit weird at first - the destruction of your base only yields a hunk of your resources being stolen.  Repairing your base takes only a few seconds and costs very little.

The overall goal in the game is pretty murky.  There are ever-increasing base upgrade goals to be met, which you will gain either by waiting for your own resources to collect, or more quickly by raiding other people's bases.  Pride in your town's strength and building levels could thus be considered a major goal of the game.

However, I would argue that the overall goal is to rank highly in the player-vs-player leagues, which require you to amass tons of trophies by successfully attacking other bases or defending your own.

Comment: Also the fact that your most likely going to have to IAP gems to even get anywhere that high up. Otherwise it takes ALOT of patience.